# Change a query string in Django?

Tags: django

I have requested the page:

```
example.com/stuff?&type=2&foo=bar&stage=unpublished
```

I want a link to the page (unset `type` and `foo` relative to previous):

```
example.com/stuff?stage=unpublished
```

And I want to do it conveniently like:

```
<a href=?{% url_params_now with foo=None type=None %}">go up</a>
```

How do I do it? Is there some inbuilt way, or some library?

---

I use the tedious

```
{{url}}?{% if type %}type={{type}}{% endif %}&{% if foo %}foo={{foo}}{% endif %}&{% if stage %}stage={{stage}}{% endif %}
```

Comment: {% url %} with params doesn't help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: @danielfranca URL params are not bound to GET variables.

Comment: how about just `?stage=unpublished` ? You dont need to explicitly set. Also, the best bet is to handle this in the view because nothing stops the user from sending arbitrary GET parameters as a part of the request.

Comment: Did you take a look to Django custom tags? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, I created my own template tag. I can call stuff like `{% urlgen a=1 b=2 %}`. its terser and neater.

```
@register.simple_tag(name = 'urlgen')
def urlgen(**kwargs):
    with_present_values = dict( [ (k,v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if v])
    return query_string_from_dict( with_present_values)
```

and

```
from django.http import QueryDict
def query_string_from_dict( dic):
    query_dictionary = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
    query_dictionary.update( dic)
    if dic:
        return '?' + query_dictionary.urlencode()
    else:
        return ''
```

Not covered here: registering template tags with Django.

Comment: Good choice :) Cleaner than if/endif.. tags

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
{{url}}?type={{type|default:""}}&foo={{foo|default:""}}&stage={{stage|default:""}}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default

Also there is a built in `default_if_none` filter.